# RabbitMQ - AMQP protocol behind an nginx proxy

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, rabbitmq

I am deploying in Kubernetes a RabbitMQ instance, for use with the AMQP protocol.

The requirements are that the RabbitMQ should work with plain User+PWD for communication with internal Kubernetes workload, but it should work publicly with User+PWD AND mTLS.

After thoroughly reviewing, RabbitMQ does not support this option, so what I did is to leave the RabbitMQ configured with plain User+PWD, and I'm trying to put an Nginx Ingress in front of the port 5672:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-external
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: default/ca-secret
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "X.X.X.X"
spec:
  ingressClassName: public-nginx
  rules:
    - host: rabbitmq.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: rabbitmq
                port:
                  number: 5672
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - rabbitmq.example.com
      secretName: rabbitmq-tls-cert
```

However, when trying to connect to port 443 from a `pika` client in python, I get the following error:

```
ssl.SSLError: Cannot create a client socket with a PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER context (_ssl.c:805)
```

What may be happening? I tried with several set of configurations, but the error is still the same. I tried locally from the Kubernetes cluster with Plain authentication and it's working as expected.